# kubuntu: wine is not get removed after removing PPA , still showing up

Tags: apt, kubuntu, wine, ppa

i'm using kubuntu 16.10 . today i installed wine PPA 1.7.35 following 
commands

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-wine/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y wine1.7
```

But, it showed some errors(i forgot them). and i tried to delete the PPA 
with this command `sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:ubuntu-wine/ppa` and i was asked to `press enter`
, and did.

but wine is still showing everywhere and `winecfg` is working too.

how should i remove it completely? [image]

Comment: Removing a PPA doesn't uninstall software that had been installed from it. Only ppa-purge (not installed by default) actually removes the PPA -and- reverts the changes made.

Comment: Why Wine v1.7? There's a more recent stable release (v1.8). If you want bleeding edge Wine there's also the current development branch (v1.9).

Answer (score 0):

Those desktop entries aren't actually part of the Wine package but of the per-user profile configuration which is never altered during package (un-)installation.

The desktop entries are created when an application run through Wine adds an entry to the (emulated) Windows start menu. The underlying files reside in `~/.local/share/applications/wine/` where you can delete them if you want.

There's (usually) a default per-user Wine environment in `~/.wine/` too if you want to get rid of all per-user resources related to Wine. If you used PlayOnLinux there's also `~/.PlayOnLinux/wineprefix/`.

Answer (score -1):

open the file manager as root, then search for wine using catfish and you should have entries under /.local/share & others. delete those files and it should be removed from your menu after you log out and back in.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! I recommend [edit]ing this answer to expand it with specific details about how to do this. (See also [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer) for general advice about what sorts of answers are considered most valuable on AskUbuntu.)